# Is possible to bypass my regex and execute any javascript?

Tags: regex, security, scripting, xss, eval

Is possible to bypass my regex and execute any javascript?

```
function json(a){ 
    if (/^\s*$/.test(a) ? 0 : /^[\],:{}\s\u2028\u2029]*$/
        .test(a.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, "@")
        .replace(/"[^"\\\n\r\u2028\u2029\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, "]")
        .replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:[\s\u2028\u2029]*\[)+/g, ""))) 

     try{ 
         return eval("(" + a + ")") 
     } catch (b) {} 
     g(Error("Invalid JSON string: " + a)) 
}
//... 
json(window.name);
```

I believe is impossible.

Comment: Could you format your code in a more readable way, please? There's a help button to the upper right of the edit window in case you don't know how.

Comment: Any reason your not using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)? This is implemented in all browsers and node.js.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30365/is-xss-possible-here-challenge

Comment: Are sure that this is "your" regex? Or are we talking about you trying to exploit [`goog.json.parse`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev-channel-js.js?spec=svn308&r=308#3964)?

Comment: All the ways I know to execute some function in JS always involve `()`, which is not allowed in the regex that is tested against.

Answer (score 2):

That code is part of [`goog.json.parse`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev-channel-js.js?spec=svn308&r=308#3964), which is a fork of Crockford's json2.js allowing additional whitespace characters.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), you'll find helpful comments explaining why those regexes prevent execution. That code has been battle-tested for years, so I doubt there's any holes.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
(true");alert(9);//"
```

is very close to a valid javascript statement and will bypass this regex.

Be careful with your regex, someone can bypass it.